# How to redirect by checking for a particular previous url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following piece of code in my controller

```
def index

 session[:previous_url] = URI(request.referer).path 

  if session[:previous_uri] != new_path
     redirect_to registration_path(id: current_user.associate_username)
   end

end
```

However this does not actually work and i get a bad URI error.
I just want to check if the request came from a particular page and if not redirect it to another page. I would also like to know if there is a better way for doing this?.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say if there is a better way, but you can make it work typing `:previous_uri` consistently:

```
session[:previous_uri] = URI(request.referer).path
```

instead of

```
session[:previous_url] = URI(request.referer).path
```

P.S. Dont forget to check you define paths properly in routes.rb